# What is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0?

Tags: java, scala

Thank you all for answering before questions.
Here I have another problem. I got an exception 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 when I write the Array as 
ArrayBoolean

I tried to find through google but couldn't.
If you know share me please.

Answer (score 6):

It means, in essence:

```
 int[] array = new int[0];
 array[0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

It means you try to write into empty array.

From javadoc of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
 * Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an 
 * illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or 
 * equal to the size of the array.
```

So, 0 is >= size of your array, so your array is empty.

Comment: but num is input number from user. How about if I put 16. It is not empty right? However it gives me error.

Comment: Aan ok. I got it. Thank you very much.